# Check if nodejs is running in screen

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, background-process, gnu-screen

I have a few nodejs processes running in different screens on a ubunutu-server. If a process in one of these screens crashed I’d like to have a script which automatically restarts the node script in the background. 
I always get solutions only checking if node is installed... is there a way to check and solve this?

Comment: register a service as 'upstart' script on linux, in order to have your node service restart when it crashes. Also, you may want to lookt at [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple loop that starts whatever script you need, in this case `npm start`:

```
while true
do
    npm start
done
```

You can add an `&` at the end if you need to.